# highchart How can I get width parent element for calculated x max in xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I get width parent element or default chart element when I define the chart for calculated x max in `xAxis`?

This is my expected code:

```
xAxis: {
    max: data.length < this.parent.width / 32 ? data.length - 1 : this.parent.width / 32,
    min: 0,
    categories: data,
    labels: {
        rotation: -40,
        style: {
            color: '#eb9123'
        },
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know what is the width of the div container where the chart belongs, then you can achieve it by `chart.chartWidth`. Also, you can update the axis on [load event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load).

```
chart: {
      events: {
        load: function () {
          var width = this.chartWidth / 32,
              dataLen = this.series[0].data.length,
              max = dataLen < width ? dataLen - 1 : width;
          console.log(max);

          this.xAxis[0].update({
            max: max
          });
        }
      }
    },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/91zbg0dx/

If you want to have that ability responsive, you have to do the same on [redraw event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw).